# Wordpress AJAX 400

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

**Problem**

Trying to run an AJAX call when an event, in this case "updated_cart_totals" (WooCommerce, but that is irrelevant here, it could be any event) but am getting the response "400".

**What i've tried (as per other threads with similar issues here)**

- Ensuring that the callback and action names are correct
- Put `wp_enqueue_script` after `wp_localize_script` as suggested in one thread
- Moved actions outside of any classes (they were previously in a class)
- Tested the ajax call by navigating to "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=totals_updated" and that works perfectly fine.

**my_plugin.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
    wp_register_script( 'request_quote', plugins_url( 'request-quote/js/display.js' ) );
    wp_localize_script(
        'request_quote',
        'request_quote_object',
        array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) )
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'request_quote' );
});

add_action( 'wp_ajax_totals_updated', 'enable_quote_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_totals_updated', 'enable_quote_request' );
function enable_quote_request(){
    echo "AJAX WORKING";
    die();
}
```

**display.js**

```
jQuery( function($){
        jQuery(document.body).on('updated_cart_totals', function () {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                action: 'totals_updated',
                url: request_quote_object.ajax_url,
                data: '',
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well it seems that the way I was calling "action" in my JS was incorrect, and that should be:

```
data: {
    action: 'totals_updated'
},
```

Not sure how so many others have got it working without that, perhaps some kind of WP update? Either way, works, and I can stop swearing to myself, for now..